# how can i make a testbech of the basic VHDL code?

Tags: vhdl

I'm a beginner to VHDL, and I've encountered the following code

```
process
    variable F: integer:=1; variable A: integer:=0;
begin 
 wait on E;
 A :=1;
 F :=A+5;
 B <= F + 1 after 5ns;
 C <= B + 2 after 10ns;
 D <= C +5 after 15ns;
 A :=A +5;
end process;
```

all of the variable and signals are initialized.
If E changes from '0' to '1' at time 20ns, how can I make a testbench code for the source code above?

Comment: It's just another piece of VHDL code. What's so hard about that?

Answer (score -1):

Due to the `wait` statement, the process does not run until the `E` signal value change, you need to write testbench for the `E` signal only.

- Method 1:

```vhd
E <= '0', '1' after 20 ns;
```

- Method 2:

```vhd
process
begin
  E <= '0'; -- set value of E at start of simulation
  wait for 20 ns;
  E <= '1'; -- change value of E when simulation reach to 20 ns;
  wait;
end process;
```

> Note: Some simulation tools, can not simulate variables in the process block. you need to convert variables to signals or report the value of them just after each statement.